# Get notification list\text using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, notifications

I saw a lot of articles about creating notifications using PowerShell and no one about getting notifications.
I found `Windows.UI.Notifications`  namespace, but it for creating notifications as well
Is it any way to read a list of unread notifications with title or text inside of it?

I want to do some actions after notification from some program is come up

Comment: So just to clarify, you're looking for something that allows PowerShell to recognize Windows Notifications that originate from another source, and then do some logic based off of those notifications?

Comment: Yes. So, I have desktop notification from chrome and I want to do some actions after it comes